# Different taxonomy term title for menu and term page

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Need help with one problem, I want to use different term title, 1-st for menu and breadcrumbs, 2-nd for term page

For example in menu and breadcrumbs: "doors"
In term page: "glasses doors"

I thought create special field for alternative title and add to page.tpl but I don't know how I can do it.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drupal_set_title()` with implementing `hook_preprocess_page()`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $langcode = $variables['language']->language;
  $term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2, $langcode);
  if (!empty($term)) {
    drupal_set_title($term->custom_field[$langcode][0]['value']);
  }
}
```

`menu_get_object()` may not work because some module may override the menu entry `taxonomy/term/%` as mentioned by [mxh](https://api.drupal.org/comment/56238#comment-56238).

If you want more robust way to retrieve the term object. Please use below snippet.

```php
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && arg(2)) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
}
if (isset($term) && !empty($term)) {
  // code.
}
```

Comment: cool, thanks! More pretty then I write for page.tpl ))
  `// Check if term page and rewrite $title
  if ( arg(1) == 'term') {
   $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));

   $title = $term->custom_field['und'][0]['value']; }`

Comment: 1-st rule "Don't forget about clear cache"))) after this operation I seen what it's not work(( 
Now I use for this this code in page.tpl
`// Check if term page no empty and rewrite $title
  if ( arg(1) == 'term') {
   $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
   $title_term = $term->field_title;
   if (!empty($title_term)) {
    $title = $title_term['und'][0]['value'];
   }
  }`

Comment: Yup, every new implemented hook function required clear cache. :)

Answer (score 0):

There a a lot of options to accomplish this.  You have a few questions listed. Breadcrumbs can be a loaded question by itself.  But Here is one option using the Menu Attributes module https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes you could fill in a Title attribute.  Then If you are using Panels, you could override the page name by using a Token of the Name attribute.  This would let your breadcrumbs and menu use the 1st title, while giving you a 2nd title.

Comment: I don't use Panel, only Views and code.
Menu Attributes don't change breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

[Jimmy Ko](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/56904/jimmy-ko) get me right way

> You can use drupal_set_title() with implementing
>   hook_preprocess_page().
>
> /**  * Implements hook_preprocess_page().  */ function
>   mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {   $langcode =
>   $variables['language']->language;   $term =
>   menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2, $langcode);   if (!empty($term)) {
>       drupal_set_title($term->custom_field[$langcode][0]['value']);   } }

But This not work for me ((( I think about it and my page.tpl code and found right variant.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    //  Check if taxonomy page
    if ( arg(1) == 'term') {

        //  load term data
        $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
        $title_term = $term->custom_field;

        //Check if custom field not empty
        if (!empty($title_term)) {
            // Set Custom Title
            drupal_set_title($title_term['und'][0]['value']);
        }
    }
}
```

For multilanuages site, maybe need this part of [Jimmy Ko](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/56904/jimmy-ko) code `$langcode = $variables['language']->language;` and chahge 'und' to $langcode )

Comment: I guess why `menu_get_object()` not working because of the reason stated in [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/56238#comment-56238) on Drupal.org